# Random Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Tags: php

In server logs I see very often there is error

> PHP Warning:  session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send
>   session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at
>   /public_html/templates/meta.php:294) in
>   /public_html/include/query.php on line 7

Seems obvious I got output started sooner...but

Errors gets generated only sometimes and I can't reproduce it this maybe because `session_start()' is inside of if statement.

This is the beginning of query.php

```
<?php
//  we are including here so that we can check user logged in or not on each and everypage  
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
    //To make the session work across multiple domains.
    session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.mydomain.com');
    session_start();        
}
```

Everywhere query.php gets included **before** meta.php

meta.php is mostly html and js with few php blocks and line 294 is in middle of some js function.

But what intrigues me most is that I get this error as well for request that do not involve these two files at all.

For example

From access log

> 66.249.72.33 - - [19/Aug/2013:22:44:30 +0100] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 7592 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1;
>   +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
>
> 66.249.72.33 - - [19/Aug/2013:22:44:30 +0100] "GET /content_files/SPIKES%20protocol.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 215267 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1;
>   +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"

and error log

> [Mon Aug 19 22:44:30 2013] [error] [client 66.249.72.33:44269] AH01215: PHP Warning:  session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /public_html/templates/meta.php:294) in /public_html/include/query.php on line 7
>
> [Mon Aug 19 22:44:30 2013] [error] [client 66.249.72.33:44269] AH01215: PHP Warning:  session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /public_html/templates/meta.php:294) in /public_html/include/query.php on line 7

As You can see at 22:44:30 google bot made 2 requests 
1st for robots.txt and he got 404 as there is no robots.txt
2nd for some pdf file

In both cases there is not php code involved but I got PHP warnings for these requests.

These are no other access logs from google bot before or after these.

General structure of code is like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['url1'])){$url1 = $_GET['url1'];}else {$url1 = "";}
if(isset($_GET['url2'])){$url2 = $_GET['url2'];}else {$url2 = "";}
require_once('include/query.php');
require_once('include/auth.php');

/* some php code */
?>

<?php include 'templates/meta.php'; ?>

//html
```

but error gets generated for requests that do not use query.php or meta.php at all as well, like in given example.

Comment: What is happening on line 294 of `/public_html/templates/meta.php`?

Comment: @MikeBrant as I wrote in my question it is middle of some js function. There is lots of html, js and php before and after. And in reality output starts way before that line but after query.php is included.

Comment: That is your problem. You cannot start outputting ANYTHING and then starting the session, as `session_start()` need to set a cookie. Typically, `session_start()` is amongst the very first lines of code executed for a request.

Comment: @MikeBrant Did You read my question fully or just first paragraph?

Comment: @Gustek I think he's already [**answered**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324409/random-cannot-send-session-cache-limiter-headers-already-sent#comment26894270_18324409) your question.

Comment: Read my question carefully, there are total of 9 lines before a `session_start()` nothing else no space, no tabs, no BOM, nothing. All these 9 lines I have posted. Error gets generated only sometimes and I see it only in server logs, can't reproduce it myself. The strange thing is it gets generated as well for request that do not involve php or do not use these 2 files at all. How I can get PHP warning if I am directly downloading pdf file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with custom 404 page.

For clarification I have to say that it is 5 years old website and I didn't design it just making some modifications.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, I find that "headers already sent" errors are actually whitespace errors. Maybe check any files that are shared between all of these pages and see if there is an extra line break or space after a closing `?>` tag. Generally I try to avoid using closing PHP tags at the end of files since they are discarded by the parser anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Headers already send error occurs mainly while an echo or any other output statement occurs before `header` function used for redirects or other stuffs.